# Stop metro in max msp

Tags: arduino

I'm working on a project for my university. I'm connecting an Arduino to Max MSP using SimpleMessageSystem. 
I read the values from the analog ports and it all works fine. 
Although there is a metro 100 with the analog read to continue reading the values of it, as they change the whole time.

My problem is... that with the reading it also bangs every millisecond or so. But I would like that bang to stop after one of my analog reads, to play a sound when it reaches a specific number.

So what I want: I want ONE bang when the sensor reaches <340 if above 340 then 0.

I hope anyone can help and understand me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed it...

From the number value from my reading I split the outcome so I use:

split 0 340 and split 340 400
The first split with outcome message 1 and the second split message 0

You then use s num to select te number and r num to receive the number elsewhere. 
You use change 666 and then select 0 1

And you connect your select to the toggle.

[image: Split value is 0]

[image: Split value is 1]

Answer (score 0):

If it's an integer stream and you want one event triggered past 320 you could do:

[int] -> [> 340] -> [change] -> [sel 1]

The > 340 is because I don't know how consistent the integer stream is.  Otherwise you could explicitly state the numbers to trigger once:
[int] -> [sel 340 ... ...]

This would create individual hard-coded patch cables for the events, refactoring that could be separate questions for the approach styles.